# Can I drag imageView gestureRecongnizer to .m file as Action?

Tags: ios, storyboard, gesture

First of all, I have open the image's User Interaction Enabled.

[image]

But why I can't drag the gesture ?

[image]

Comment: you can see this tutorial that will help you to add gesture https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The `gestureRecognizers` in Outlet Collections is a outlet to the gesture recognizers of that view, not an action of its gesture recognizers.

What you need to do is adding a gesture recognizer to the image view by dragging one from the `Object Library` and adding its action

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the gesture like this:

1. Drag a TapGesture Recognizer to the ViewController in storyboard:
   [image]
2. You should write a `IBAction` method in the ViewController.m:

```

```
-(IBAction)tapGesture:(id)sender {

}
```

```

3. Drag the TapGesture Recognizer to ViewController, then choose the delegate and the `tapGesture:` method:

   [image]
4. Then you can drag the imageView's gestureRecognizers to the gesture:

   [image]

The function you write in ViewController.m is what you want.

Comment: what software do you use for image editing as in this answer?